# What would i add to this code to make 'mylives' go down (pygame)

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame, random
from pygame import*
pygame.init()
myname=input('What is your name')
#set the window size
window= pygame.display.set_mode((800,600) ,0,24)
pygame.display.set_caption("Fruit Catch")
#game variables
myscore=0
mylives=3
mouth_x=300
fruit_x=250
fruit_y=75
fruitlist=['broccoli.gif','chicken.gif']
#prepare for screen
myfont=pygame.font.SysFont("Britannic Bold", 55)
label1=myfont.render(myname, 1, (240, 0, 0))
label3=myfont.render(str(mylives), 1, (20, 255, 0))
#grapchics
fruit=pygame.image.load('data/chicken.png')
mouth=pygame.image.load('data/v.gif')
backGr=pygame.image.load('data/kfc.jpg')
#endless loop
running=True
while running:
    if fruit_y>=460:#check if at bottom, if so prepare new fruit
       fruit_x=random.randrange(50,530,1)
       fruit_y=75
       fruit=pygame.image.load('data/'+fruitlist[random.randrange(0,2,1)])
       caught= fruit_x>=mouth_x and fruit_x<=mouth_x+300
    else:fruit_y+=5

   #check collision
    if fruit_y>=440:
            if fruit_x>=mouth_x and fruit_x<=mouth_x+300 :
                    myscore+=1
                    fruit_y=600#move it off screen
                    pygame.mixer.music.load('data/eating.wav')




    #detect key events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if (event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN):
                if (event.key==pygame.K_LEFT):
                        mouth_x-=55
                if (event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT):
                        mouth_x+=55

    label3=myfont.render(str(mylives), 1, (20, 255, 0))
    label2=myfont.render(str(myscore), 1, (20, 255, 0))
    window.blit(backGr,(0,0))
    window.blit(mouth, (mouth_x,440))
    window.blit(fruit,(fruit_x, fruit_y))
    window.blit(label1, (174, 537))
    window.blit(label2, (700, 157))
    window.blit(label3, (700, 400))
    pygame.display.update()
```

It's basically a simple fruit catching game
How could I make it so that if there is no contact between the bowl and the fruit my lives go down one?
Ive managed to get +1 score working, but no the -1 score.
Any ideas guys?
I'm new to python and pygame so it is probably something pretty simple that  I haven't thought of.

Comment: Please do not ask the same basic question a second time with a massive code dump (again).  Just delete this question and focus on your first one.

Comment: not that it is important but your tab lengths are all different. it will still run fine. you might want to change it for clarity's sake though.

Comment: You could edit the first question by the way

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to either lose a life if you miss or add one to your score if you hit, just use an else. If you hit, +1 score, else, -1 lives. Here is an example:

```
if fruit_x>=mouth_x and fruit_x<=mouth_x+300 :
    myscore+=1
    fruit_y=600#move it off screen
    pygame.mixer.music.load('data/eating.wav')
else:
    mylives-=1
```